# Function within constructor throwing error undefined at accessing public constructor variable

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I've been cleaning up a lot of animation code and I've run into a bunch of similar but different problems.

This time I have a constructor within a constructor function - but thats not the problem, at least on the face of it.

The problem is that within that nested constructor function, there's a normal function this.draw, which should refer to this.ctx. But this isn't happening. I thought at first maybe its because ctx somehow wasn't getting declared at load-time before it was being referred to, but it didn't fix it when I put `this.ctx = "";` just to give it a placeholder.

Whats up here? This is the prototype call for the nested constructor function, with the .draw function trying to reference its this.ctx:

```js
DrawDeerbra.prototype.Circle = function(){
  this.ctx = "";
  if(this.constructor.count1 >= this.constructor.count2){
    this.ctx = this.constructor.ctx2;
    this.count = 2;
    ++this.constructor.count2;
  } else {
    this.ctx = this.constructor.ctx1;
    this.count = 1;
    ++this.constructor.count1;
  }


  this.draw = function(){ 
      var ctx = this.ctx;
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
      ctx.shadowBlur = (this.size*2) * Math.abs(Math.sin(this.shadowFrame));
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

This is where the .draw from the nested Circle constructor is called --

```js
DrawDeerbra.prototype.anim = function(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  this.update();
}

DrawDeerbra.prototype.update = function(){
  ++this.frame;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < this.circles.length; ++i){
    var circ = this.circles[i];
    circ.update();
    circ.draw();
    
    if(circ.pos.x - circ.size > w ||
       circ.pos.y - circ.size > h ||
       circ.pos.x + circ.size < 0 ||
       circ.pos.y + circ.size < 0){
      
      if(circ.count === 1) --count1;
      else --count2;
      
      this.circles[i] = new Circle;
    }
  }
}
```

Before this there is a function that populates the circle array with the nested Circle constructor, and then calls .anim and .update

Comment: Could you please show where you are calling `draw`? Most likely you have an incorrect context.

Comment: Draw is likely passed as a call back. As answered multiple times; you should pass something that uses bind or pass a closure.

Comment: Are you positive its been answered multiple times? The question was different each time, can you say how it was actually the same instead of just telling this is the case?

Comment: What are those `anim` and `Circle` variables? Do you expect them to be the values of your properties?

Comment: Yeah they are part of the DrawDeerbra class. Circle is a little class used to populate an array used for the animation. They should both be methods of DrawDeerbra. They are used to draw the animation.